# how can i use put/delete methods in symfony2.0.x

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to enable the methods put / delete in symfony, but I always get this error:

405 Method Not Allowed

routing.yml

```
album_list:
     pattern: /
     defaults: { _controller: "AcmeAlbumBundle:Album:list"}
     requirements:
        _method: GET

album_show:
    pattern:  /{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "AcmeAlbumBundle:Album:show" }
    requirements:
        _method: GET

album_index:
    pattern:  /index
    defaults: { _controller: "AcmeAlbumBundle:Album:new" }


album_put:
    pattern:  /{id}
    defaults: { _controller: "AcmeAlbumBundle:Album:put" }
    requirements:
        _method: PUT


album_delete:
    pattern:  /{id}
    defaults: { _controller: "AcmeAlbumBundle:Album:delete" }
    requirements:
        _method: DELETE
```

Comment: how are you calling these URLs?

Comment: ajax.dojo with put/delete methods

Comment: i can access these routes: album_list/album_show/album_index if i use post method in album_put it works fine but i want to use put and delete. Thank you

Comment: Try to move the PUT/DELETE route at the top of your routing.yml file. To make sure that symfony correctly route the POST/DELETE routes, also try to `GET /2323?_method=PUT` with your client.

Comment: AdrienBrault i tried but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

I also had this bug with early releases of Symfony (RC4 in July 2011). I used only POST methods.

You should upgrade to newest version to make it work but unfortunately, upgrading is not always that easy.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, i have upgraded to version 2.1.1 and still the same error.

Comment: I have opened the issue one year ago : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1675 ; I don't know why I closed it, I can't remember but I used only POST methods in my project. Maybe you could reopen it.

Comment: Hello Nicolas, I think we can't define the routes by methods. I changed the routes with different patterns. functioned normally

Comment: OK. We both misunderstood the doc :) Have fun, Symfony 2 is great, I had some good times with it.